Inversify @provide(Service) Error Cannot access 'Service' before initialization when in Test
I'm currently build an app with IOC using inversify and inversify-binding-decorators, but when I create a test for the service that using @provide(Service) it got error Cannot access 'Service' before initialization
My code look like this:
// src/services/userService.ts

import { provide } from 'inversify-binding-decorators';

@provide(UserService)
export class UserService {
  public get(): User {
    return {
        id: 1,
        name: 'test',
        age: 15
    }
  }
}


// src/services/userService.test.ts

import { UserService } from './userService';

describe('UserService', () => {
  let service: UserService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new UserService();
  });

  describe('User GET Test', () => {
    it(`Should return user data with name 'test'`, async () => {
      const data = await service.get();
      expect(data.name).toEqual('test');
    });
  });
});

// babel.config.json
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }],
    ["@babel/preset-typescript", { "allowDeclareFields": true }]
  ],
  "plugins": [["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]]
}


Is there any error with my code?
Thanks in advance
